# Laço de repetição C# componentes asp

Tags: c#, loop, genéricos, .net

Teria como fazer um laço de repetição nesse caso?

```
PaperBLL paperBLL = new PaperBLL();
List<PaperEO> papers = paperBLL.SelectPapers();
HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 1).capa;
HyperLink2.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 2).capa;
HyperLink3.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 3).capa;
HyperLink4.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 4).capa;
HyperLink5.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 5).capa;
HyperLink6.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 6).capa;
HyperLink7.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 7).capa;
HyperLink8.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 8).capa;
HyperLink9.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 9).capa;
HyperLink10.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 10).capa;
HyperLink11.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 11).capa;
HyperLink12.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + papers.First(x => x.id == 12).capa;

(...)

<ul>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/01.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/01.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/02.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/02.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/03.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/03.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/04.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/04.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/05.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/05.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/06.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/06.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/07.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/07.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/08.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/08.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/09.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/09.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink10" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/10.png" rel="Shadowbox[Vocation]"><asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" Width="131" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/10.png" /></asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isto está em um *Code Behind*?

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, sim está!

Comment: De curiosidade, não caberia algo do tipo `HyperLink[12].ImageUrl` na sua solução?

Comment: @Bacco, não conheço essa "técnica", posso fazer isso?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo essa é justamente a minha dúvida :) Talvez até dê, mas o lambda pode nao funcionar como esperado.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo vi que você já conseguiu a solução. Resolveu tudo? Resolveu esta parte também `papers.First(x => x.id == 12).capa`? Ou você não precisa mais disto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja uma situação a ser solucionada com um controle [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Você pode setar qualquer classe que implemente *IEnumerable* ou *IListSource* como [fonte de dados](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Durante o evento `ItemDataBound` você terá à disposição o objeto membro da coleção e todos os controles presentes no *ItemTemplate*.

### Pagina.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="meuHyperLink" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

### Pagina.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var minhaColecao = new List<string>(); //Assuma como sendo sua colecao.

        Repeater1.DataSource = minhaColecao;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (string) e.Item.DataItem; // No seu caso, substitua o string cast por PaperEO.
        var controle = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("meuHyperLink");
        controle.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/MultiMercadoLibertyExclusiva/Capas/" + item;
    }
```

Comment: Dentro de <ItemTemplate>, eu teria que criar todos HyperLink? Igual você fez para "1"?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Não - apenas um; note que no evento ItemDataBound o controle é 'procurado' via método `FindControl`. O controle Repeater irá criar tantas instâncias do controle quanto necessárias (uma para cada membro da coleção. Eu vou editar minha resposta para tornar o nome do controle mais claro.

Comment: Deu certo @OnoSendai, economizou muitas linhas de código, hahahahah. Obg!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo fico feliz que tenha funcionado! Como dica adicional, vale mencionar que você pode incluir tantos controles quanto quiser no `ItemTemplate`. Apenas lembre-se de usar o cast para o tipo correto quando utilizar `FindControl`, porque este método apenas retorna `Object`s.

Comment: Tem como eu setar que o id comece do 1 ao invés do 0?

Comment: Você diz o conteúdo criado automaticamente pelo `Repeater`? Eu não tenho como verificar neste momento, mas eu diria que não é possível controlar o valor inicial. Vou verificar mais tarde pra você.

Answer (score 1):

Use uma função genérica:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (varcontrol in controlCollection)
    {
        if (control is T)
            yield return (T)control;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
foreach (var link in GetControlList<HyperLink>(Page.Controls))
{
    // Coloque a lógica aqui.
}
```

Comment: Não entrou no foreach!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Qual deles?

Comment: foreach (var link in GetControlList<HyperLink>(Page.Controls))

Comment: Devolva o valor de `GetControlList` numa lista e faça um debug. O que aparece nela?

Comment: Ela veio Nulla!

Comment: Os tipos dos seus objetos são `HyperLink` mesmo? Eles aparecem dentro de `Page.Controls`?

Comment: Sim. Editei a pergunta.